# Отображение номера телефона в верстке письма mail.ru

Tags: вёрстка, email, mail.ru

В верстке письма присутствует номер телефона. При отображении на mail.ru номер телефона оборачивается в < span > и в нем применяются свои стили. как это побороть? Ссылка с номером телефона должна оставаться ссылкой, но при этом не применять стили от mail.ru

Код прописан в шаблоне так:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'arial';
  color: #abafac !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  letter-spacing: .7px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #abafac;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -6px;
}
```

```html
<a href="tel:88008888888">8 800 888 88 88</a>
```

а в mail.ru отображается так:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'arial';
  color: #abafac !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  letter-spacing: .7px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #abafac;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -6px;
}
```

```html
<a target="_blank" rel="noopener"><span class="js-phone-number highlight-phone" data-title="Позвонить через Веб-Агент">8 800 888 88 88</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Получается, что mail.ru видоизменяет Вашу ссылку, в последствии обрабатывая её JavaScript'ом. Это сделано в целях защиты. С этим Вы ничего поделать не можете, однако стили Вы можете изменить, добавив свои со значением !important;

Например:

```
.js-phone-number {
    font-size: 100px !important;
}
```

Это при условии, что Ваш CSS mail.ru не затирает.

Comment: увы, это не помогает. уже пробовала такой вариант

Comment: Значит Ваш CSS заменяется или переопределяется.